# How to get relative path as String of an image file in same project folder?

Tags: java, file

[image]

please Don't degrade a question champs !! Thanks for watching !!
I want to get relative path for the `"Tulips.jpg"(src/resource)`. Do I need to keep these file in `webcontent`? Please help me to find out.

```
One way -// `private static final String FILE_PATH = ".\\WebContent\\uploadFiles\\Tulips.jpg";`
Another way -// `private static final String FILE_PATH = "D://uploadFiles/Tulips.jpg";`

    //  private static final String FILE_PATH = "/image.process/resource";

    URL url =     ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/image.process/resource/Tulips.jpg");
    String filename = "Tulips.jpg";

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("image/*")
    public Response getFile() {


         System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
                  System.getProperty("user.dir"));

        File file = new File(url + filename);

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
        response.header("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=image_from_server.jpg");
        return response.build();

    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code as how are you doing it?

Comment: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/Tulips.jpg")`

Comment: please Don't degrade a question champs !!
Thanks for watching !!

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can use do is get the classloader from current thread and get the resource.

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("Tulips.jpg")
```

Comment: Got it. I can implement this in two ways.
1) By loading the classpath
2) Keeping the file into user_derectory folder.
Thanks for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this into your code (main method preferably)

```
System.out.println(System.getproperty("user.dir"));
```

Place tulips.png into the folder printed out on runtime, as this will print out the folder your program is looking in. If you wish to keep your directory structure, move your resources folder to the folder printed

Comment: can we change that working directory? It is showing the eclipse location.

Comment: What you should do instead is modify the file path to start at the working directory, so instead of resources/tulips.png it could be "image.process/Java Resources/resource/tulips.png"